# Integral of $dy/dx$ confusion

Tags: integration

Why is $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{dx} dx = y + c$, but for example $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{dx} y dx = \dfrac{1}{2} y^2 + c$ instead of $\dfrac{1}{2} y^3 + c$?

Comment: Why should it be $y^3$? If you differentiate, you see that $\frac{d}{dx}(y(x)^2) = 2y(x)\frac{d y}{dx}(x)$.

Comment: Differentiate each side of the equalities.

Comment: @DanielFischer Why does $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ become $y$ in the first case, but not in the second case?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question: we are to find a function such that, after differentiation, it becomes $ydy/dx.$ Namely, $dy/dx$ does not become $y$ in the first case.

Comment: Does it become clearer if you write $y'(x)$ instead of $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, because in the second case then you'd take the integral of the deriative of y times the integral of y, and my problem still remains.

Comment: @Phaptitude I reitirate: differentiate each side of the equalities.

Comment: @GitGud It hasn't really helped me in the second case..

Comment: @Phaptitude Well, in the second case, you'd have to integrate by parts, or make note of the observation Daniel Fischer provided you in his first comment.

Comment: @Phaptitude $\left(\int y'(x)y(x)\rm dx\right)'=y'(x)y(x)=\left(\dfrac{(y(x))^2}{2}\right)'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *and abusing* the mathematical notation as sometimes is done when dealing with differential equations, what you really have here is

$$\int\frac{dy}{\color{red}{dx}}\color{red}{dx}=\int 1\cdot dy=y+C\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;\frac{d}{dy}(y+C)=1$$

OTOH,

$$\int\frac{dy}{\color{red}{dx}}y\,\color{red}{dx}=\int y\,dy=\frac{y^2}2+C\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\frac d{dy}\left(\frac12y^2+C\right)=y$$

Comment: This is quite logical, but I didn't know you were actually allowed to do this

Comment: Well, *formally* you may not be allowed to, yet *practically* you are. The difference is that in basic mathematics the expression $\;\frac{dy}{dx}\;$ is one single thing, *not* a fraction, **yet** when we work with differentials we see we can actually take them, in cases like this one, as fractions and separate their numerator, denominator and etc. Please do note this may heavily depend on what you're said/given in class...

Comment: Well, it is high school, and the class is not rigourous at all, it was basically just a quick intro to diff eq just to use it in a physics context later (drop a ball from certain height, with friction, etc.).

Comment: Oh, if it is to use for high school physics (orm in fact, I think that for physics *at any level*), then I'm almost 100% sure you can separate that fraction without any remorse. Physicists are well known for saying they know mathematics and thus they think they're allowed to do whatever they want...they're nice people usually, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me integrate it out:
$$\int y'ydx=y^2-\int yy'dx,$$
by integrating by parts. Hence $\int yy'dx=(1/2)y^2.$
Hope this helps.
And feel free to ask if something above is unclear.

Comment: I think we shouldn't be explaining through integration by parts when it is clear that the question was asked with insufficient understanding of integration.

Comment: I thought that this insufficient understanding ought to be fixed after integrating by parts. Anyway, it can still come in handy. :P

Answer (score -1):

I have another question and i hope someone can clarify it:

How do you find out what this is: $\int \frac{dy}{dx}$